# What is the video codec name of videos made through the Canon 600d DSLR

Tags: dslr, video

I need to know the name of the codec?
They have the file extension of .mov  but i need to know what codec that is.

What is the video codec name of videos made through the Canon 600d DSLR?

Comment: Have you tried using [MediaInfo](http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download) to analyse it?

Comment: Anyway, my 60D seems to make QuickTime/MPEG-4/Motion JPEG 2000 videos. The 600D surely makes the same video format.

Comment: the 5D MK II records h.264 - as does the 5D MK III or 700D, see here: http://www.canon.co.uk/For_Home/Product_Finder/Cameras/Digital_SLR/EOS_5D_Mark_III/index.aspx#p-specification13
and here: http://www.canon.co.uk/For_Home/Product_Finder/Cameras/Digital_SLR/EOS_700D/index.aspx#p-specification13

Sepcification -> file type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Canon DSLRs, including 600D use the same video codec:

- *Codec*: MPEG-4 Part 10 / AVC / H.264
- *Profile*: Baseline
- *Level*: 5.0
- *Bitrate mode*: CBR ± 40 Mbit/s maximum average
- *PAL*: 1080p25, 1080p24, 720p50, 480p50
- *NTSC*: 1080p30, 1080p24, 720p60, 480p60
- *Colorspace*: 8-bit YUV 4:2:0 Rec. 709

Many of the higher-end models have an additional **All-I mode**:

- *Profile*: High (without CABAC)
- *Level*: 5.1
- *Bitrate mode*: VBR ± 100 Mbit/s maximum average

Comment: It isn't low end DSLRs it is all DSLRs - whether you buy a 700D or a 5D MK III/1D X.
THe cnema 1D may be an exception and video cameras aren't DSLRs.

Comment: You are right, I'll correct that

Answer (score 1):

I can just copy my answer from the comment:

Canon SLRs encode video using h.264 - use of Magic Lantern will give you control over the bitrate which is not available by default.
The standard Canon codec is available on any spec sheet for Canon cameras - such as the 700D or 5D MK III (my 5D MK II also uses h.264)

Go to Specifications -> file type for the codec information.

Source 1: http://www.canon.co.uk/For_Home/Product_Finder/Cameras/Digital_SLR/EOS_5D_Mark_III/index.aspx#p-specification13

Source 2:
http://www.canon.co.uk/For_Home/Product_Finder/Cameras/Digital_SLR/EOS_700D/index.aspx#p-specification13